# Differences between .ContextMenu and .ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

What are the differences between `.ContextMenu` and `.ContextMenuStrip` in Windows Forms?

I already know what a `ContextMenu` is, but how is `ContextMenuStrip` different from `ContextMenu`?

Comment: Yes I checked MSDN first but no useful info.

Comment: Gee why the downvotes?

FYI, almost all StackOverflow questions about C# can be answered by MSDN, Google, Bing, and the Internet. 

It's worth asking here, because developers may want to find the answers first in StackOverflow!

Comment: I downvoted every answer (but not the question) because "ContextMenusStrip replaces ContextMenu" is a big yawn.  Of course it does.  The question asked was  *what are the differences?*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Good point. I will continue waiting for a better answer then.

I am expecting something like "Use ContextMenu if you want to do this; And use ContextMenuStrip if you want this..."

Answer (score 51, accepted):

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=606224&seqNum=2

> You might wonder why Microsoft has replaced a valuable and popular
>   control with a newcomer. The `ContextMenuStrip` control takes a good
>   idea and makes it better. It works just like the `ContextMenu` control.
>   You still attach a `ContextMenuStrip` control to another user control by
>   changing that control’s `ContextMenuStrip` property. However, Microsoft
>   has substantially improved the features you can add to a
>   `ContextMenuStrip` cont...

Look at the examples at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx

> `ContextMenuStrip` replaces `ContextMenu`. You can associate a
>   `ContextMenuStrip` with any control, and a right mouse click
>   automatically displays the shortcut menu. You can show a
>   `ContextMenuStrip` programmatically by using the Show method.
>   `ContextMenuStrip` supports cancelable Opening and Closing events to
>   handle dynamic population and multiple-click scenarios.
>   `ContextMenuStrip` supports images, menu-item check state, text, access
>   keys, shortcuts, and cascading menus.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip.aspx

> If a `ContextMenu` has also been assigned to the control, the
>   `ContextMenu` takes precedence over the `ContextMenuStrip`.

Comment: The last point here, I think, answers the question. So basically, stay away from ContextMenu altogether and use ContextMenuStrip instead.

Answer (score 9):

From the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx)

> ContextMenuStrip replaces ContextMenu.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this. MSDN is such a haystack, there can be many pages about one control, and this one answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx), the ContextMenuStrip replaces the ContextMenu class:

> Although ContextMenuStrip replaces and adds functionality to the
>   ContextMenu control of previous versions, ContextMenu is retained for
>   both backward compatibility and future use if you choose.

Source: [MSDN - ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx)

***Edit:** why the -1?*

Comment: Thats bad sport, downvoting and not commenting. How would one learn from that..?

Comment: The -1 is because you didn't answer the question in a non-trivial way. The OP was asking *what the differences are,* and I didn't see any value in your answer restating the obvious.

Comment: I disagree with you. At the time of writing, there were no answers yet. The question is 'how is ContextMenuStrip different from ContextMenu', and I've quoted the answer from the MSDN. Anyway; I'd like to know what I did wrong after a downvote.

Comment: And this is why I never comment about my downvotes.  I always get into an argument.

Comment: Editing your question just to add "Why the -1?" seems ... unhelpful.

Comment: Voting down without reason as well. See my previous comment: I'd like to know what I did wrong to improve.

Comment: Voting down is just a way of someone saying "This answer is not useful" to me, you shouldn't take it personally. If you get one sympathy up-vote for every 5 down-votes you still break even. Like the other answers here, it points people at the documentation without actually answering the question of "What are the differences?".

Answer (score 2):

[contextMenu - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx)
and
[contextMenuStrip - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx)

contextMenu - Represents a shortcut menu. Although ContextMenuStrip replaces and adds functionality to the ContextMenu control of previous versions, ContextMenu is retained for both backward compatibility and future use if you choose.

ContextMenuStrip replaces and adds functionality to the ContextMenu control of previous versions

Answer (score 1):

If you hoover over `ContextMenu` you'll notice that `ContextMenuStrip` replaces it but `ContextMenu` has been left for compatibility purposes.