# Richtextbox context menu focus cursor wont change

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, richtextbox

I have extended richtextbox and added context menu as shown below

```
 Public Sub New()           
        Dim contextMenu As ContextMenu = New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu()
        Dim menuItem As New MenuItem("Cut")        
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem)
        menuItem = New MenuItem("Copy")           
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem)
        menuItem = New MenuItem("Paste")            
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem)
        Me.ContextMenu = contextMenu
End Sub
```

But it gives a menu when I right click on rich textbox . but cursor will be not be changed to arrow when we place cursor over menu. It will be like a cursor which we get richtextbox by default. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the old `ContextMenu` you ought to use the new `ContextMenuStrip`.

```
Public Sub New()
    Dim contextMenu As ContextMenuStrip = New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip()
    Dim menuItem As New ToolStripMenuItem("Cut")
    contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem)
    menuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem("Copy")
    contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem)
    menuItem = New ToolStripMenuItem("Paste")
    contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem)
    Me.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu
End Sub
```

Here's a related SO post about the [differences between .ContextMenu and .ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442292/in-net-what-are-the-differences-between-contextmenu-and-contextmenustrip).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the cursor type you can alter the Cursor property of the control.

E.g. If I have a Label called HandLbl and want the cursor to change to a hand I can alter its cursor property (on form load in this example).

```
HandLbl.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
```

See here for a more complete example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There's also a whole bunch of cursor types you can pick from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx